# Как в laravel проверить сколько раз пользователь неправильно ввёл пароль?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно что бы после того как пользователь при логине 5 раз ввёл неправильный пароль показывалась капча

Comment: Пишите в сессию количество попыток ввода. Далее читайте количество этих попыток и выдавайте капчу.

Comment: а если нет сессии?

Comment: Пишите куда-то в другое место, например в кэш. Только тут не совсем понятно, как идентифицировать посетителя.

Comment: @JonnyManowar, не надо считать для конкретного пользователя. Делайте так: если у формы за 15-20-30-45 секунды было 3 ошибки ввода, то в ней показывайте капчу и количество ошибок храните для формы, а не для пользователя. Если у вас перебор паролей пойдет со 100 тыс. адресов, то отслеживание ошибок на каждом пользователе вас не спасет.

Comment: можно писать в базу неверные попытки

Answer (score 1):

Laravel в trait ThrottlesLogins, и так считает попытка на вход.

А файл App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php может принять следующие параметры:

```
protected $maxLoginAttempts = 10; // Кол-во попыток
protected $lockoutTime = 300; // Время игнора
```

Ты можешь переопределить один из методов ThrottlesLogins, и вместо вызова локера, передать в шаблон, что должна вызваться капча.